# Broken UI Text 5.4.2p3

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm having an issue with some UI Text objects in my company's project (sorry if I may not give some details, since I cannot share everything) where sometimes they break. In the print screen below I show you the editor window but this happens on runtime as well. In the editor I just need to target the window or move the view so they refresh but in runtime this is not so easily fixed.
Some details that might help:

1. These text components are dynamic and use a non-native font; I've
   tried to use .SetAllDirty() after the changes but it won't work;
2. I've seen people speaking about clearing the characterinfo but
   sometimes works others not;
3. I've also found a solution that pushes
   them 10 units in the "z" axis but that doesn't smells me right. We
   have lot's of text objects to pull and most of them are
   instantiated;

Thank you for your attention towards this issue and for any solutions that you might give. I'll try to answer them as soon as I can.

[Broken UI Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8QrM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is [a known bug of Unity](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ui-images-and-static-texts-glitch-on-5-dot-3).

I've also got this bug, but you can try to send a bug report to Unity.

You can send one by using the shortcut at the start menu. (Unity [version] > report a problem), if you don't see it, go to Unity, then `Help > Report a problem`.

Or you can try to report the bug to the  [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com).

Comment: Hello @jeuxjeux20! Thank you for your reply! I've posted a comment on the issue tracker page you linked stating the version where it still occurs :) I will sent a ticket as well so this issue can be solved as quickly as possible.

Comment: @MiguelF Also try to update Unity ;), now there is Unity 5.5.1.

Comment: I would but updates are not that easy to make when you are working in a company. Some things get broken and that's why we cannot immediately update :s

Comment: @MiguelF ikr ;x. I dunno if there are a lot of changes in 5.5 tho